# Angular 5 | Get height on element click

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

I am currently trying to get a height of an element which I click on in a sidebar I am working on in order to show sub menus. I have currently got this code...

```
<li (click)="newsExpanded = !newsExpanded; getMargin($event)" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <a>
        <i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i>
            <span>News</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left sidebar__sub_menu_icon"></i>
            <ul class="sidebar__sub_menu" [class.expanded]="newsExpanded">
                 <li>
                     <a>Create New Post</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a>View All Posts</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
     </a>
</li>
```

So when the news is expanded it adds the class of expanded which just displays block on the sub menu, that is working fine but I want to add a margin bottom to the inner ul on the click of the outer li. This would have to be the height of the inner ul. You can see that I've done a class of `getMargin` however, this doesn't do anything currently and it's what I'm trying to figure out.

Any help would be appreciated and if their is a better way to this then please tell me, I am new to Angular so any feedback I am grateful for.

Comment: What is `getMargin($event)` look like? There isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: `getMargin` is currently empty, it just logs out the event

Comment: so you didn't try anything then? please see [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the height of the clicked element using the `$event` you should do the following:

```
onClick($event): void {
    let clientHeight = $event.target.clientHeight; //Height + padding without borders
    let offsetHeight = $event.target.offsetHeight; //Height + padding with borders

    //if you need the element plus margin-top/bottom
    let compStyle = window.getComputedStyle($event.target)
    clientHeight += parseInt(compStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-top'));
    clientHeight += parseInt(compStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1apnhb

---

Here you are MDN docs of [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight). Also you can take a look of [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

Comment: With angular then, how would I then add the height on as a margin-bottom? I've tried `style.display.marginBottom` but I guessed that wouldn't work, I've tried doing a Google search but nothings really coming.

Comment: Have you seen my update? You need to get the computed styles and add it the client or offset height. I have updated my demo too. Check for `fullHeight` property in it.